# restrict the number of connections in postgres using an ip address

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to restrict the number of connections in postgres, using the ip address of machine, since i'm not able to find which ip address is tagged to which user / role.

Comment: You can limit number of connections by setting the max_connections = 100  parameter in the config file. You can use something like pg_pool to limit incoming connections also. http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.5.4/doc/pgpool-en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implicitly you can do it with pgbouncer - at least 1.7 version supports hba file, so you can bond db+user+ip and set limit for db+user in ini file. This way limiting connections to IP or network.

explicitly you can try using HAProxy's or just `IPTABLES` (I think prefered way)

lastly you can write some monkey job that will check number of connection from `pg_stat_activity.client_addr` and `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where client_addr = 'x.x.x.x' order by query_started desc limit 10` (to keep first 10 connections), but this way is an awful wheel for such task I'd say.